# Elasticsearch Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'

Tags: java, elasticsearch, cmd, jvm, elastic-stack

I am getting this exception when run elasticsearch.bat  Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Here is my jvm.options file

```
################################################################
##
## JVM configuration
##
################################################################
##
## WARNING: DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. If you want to override the
## JVM options in this file, or set any additional options, you
## should create one or more files in the jvm.options.d
## directory containing your adjustments.
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/@project.minor.version@/jvm-options.html
## for more information.
##
################################################################



################################################################
## IMPORTANT: JVM heap size
################################################################
##
## The heap size is automatically configured by Elasticsearch
## based on the available memory in your system and the roles
## each node is configured to fulfill. If specifying heap is
## required, it should be done through a file in jvm.options.d,
## which should be named with .options suffix, and the min and
## max should be set to the same value. For example, to set the
## heap to 4 GB, create a new file in the jvm.options.d
## directory containing these lines:
##
## -Xms4g
## -Xmx4g
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/@project.minor.version@/heap-size.html
## for more information
##
################################################################


################################################################
## Expert settings
################################################################
##
## All settings below here are considered expert settings. Do
## not adjust them unless you understand what you are doing. Do
## not edit them in this file; instead, create a new file in the
## jvm.options.d directory containing your adjustments.
##
################################################################

-XX:+UseG1GC

## JVM temporary directory
-Djava.io.tmpdir=${ES_TMPDIR}

## heap dumps

# generate a heap dump when an allocation from the Java heap fails; heap dumps
# are created in the working directory of the JVM unless an alternative path is
# specified
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# exit right after heap dump on out of memory error
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError

# specify an alternative path for heap dumps; ensure the directory exists and
# has sufficient space
@heap.dump.path@

# specify an alternative path for JVM fatal error logs
@error.file@

## GC logging
-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=@loggc@:utctime,level,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
```

I have installed the elastic zip filed and add the bin to the environment variables and tried to run elasticsearch.bat command and got the exception.
error:
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.JvmOption.flagsFinal(JvmOption.java:113)
at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.JvmOption.findFinalOptions(JvmOption.java:80)
at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.MachineDependentHeap.determineHeapSettings(MachineDependentHeap.java:59)
at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:140)
at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.JvmOptionsParser.determineJvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:92)
at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerProcess.createProcess(ServerProcess.java:214)
at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerProcess.start(ServerProcess.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerProcess.start(ServerProcess.java:91)
at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerCli.startServer(ServerCli.java:234)
at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerCli.execute(ServerCli.java:91)
at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:54)
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:50)
at org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher.main(CliToolLauncher.java:64)

Comment: What version of Java are you are using?  The CMS GC was removed in Java 14.

Comment: it is java 1.8..0

Comment: and it is ignored when I run the command, the bundled one is used

Comment: What's the version of the bundle java runtime?

Comment: it is java  19 --

Comment: Well that explains why you are being told that option has been removed.  Now ... what does the batch file say?  Apparently it is not looking at that jvm.options file.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward solution to your question is:
Add "-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions" to your JVM option